# Parse.com how to investigate excessive amount of requests

Tags: parse-platform

I'm developing a basic messaging system on the Parse.com at the moment and I have noticed in the Events Analytics screen I'm hitting 30,000+ requests per day. This is a shock considering I'm the only person using the system at the moment. Obviously with a few users I would blow my API request limit straight away.

[image]

I'm pretty experienced with Parse.com these days, so I'm lean with queries and I'm alert to not putting finds, saves, retrieves, etc in `for` loops. I also understand that `saveAll()` on an array of ParseObjects doesn't always limit the request count to 1 (depending on relationships inside that object).

So how does one track down where the excessive calls are coming from?

[image]

I see the above Analytics > Performance > Served Requests data, but how do I drill down to see if cloud code or iOS is the culprit?

Current solution is to effectively unit test each block of Parse code and look at the results in above screen.

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of others who may happen upon this thread with the same questions, I found some techniques to hunt down where excessive requests are coming from.

1) Parse's documentation on the API's themselves is really good, but there isn't a lot of information / guides for the admin interfaces. Under:  **Analytics -> Explorer -> Make a table** there is a capability to download all the requests for a specific day (to import into a spreadsheet). The data isn't very detailed though and the dates are epoch timestamps, so hard to follow. At least you can see [Request Type, Class, Installation ID] e.g. ["find", "MyParseClass", "Cloud Code"].

2) My other technique was to add custom Analytic events to the code. So in Cloud Code for example, I added the following line to each beforeSave and afterSave event:
`Parse.Analytics.track('MyClass_beforeSave', null);`

3) Obviously, Parse logs these calls in the Logs window, but given you can only see the most recents transactions and can't clear them, I found it mostly unhelpful in tracking down the excessive calls.